# pyzmq pair sockets stuck

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I am following the Bidirectional pair socket example from the pyzmq documentation. I created two files, 
socket1.py with this code

```py
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:{}".format(port))
print("Socket created")

i = 0
while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print("socket: msg recved")
    print(msg)
    socket.send_string("hello from 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

and socket2.py with this code:

```py
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:{}".format(port))
print("Socket created")

i = 0
while True:
    socket.send_string("hello from 2")
    print("socket2: msg sent")
    msg = socket.recv()
    print(msg)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

I run both the files in 2 separate terminals but it prints the following messages in terminal1 and terminal2 respectively:

```sh
Socket created
```

```sh
Socket created
socket2: msg sent
```

I am not able to understand why socket1 is not receiving the msg sent by socket2 and is stuck at `socket.recv()`. I would really appreciate any help. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The first example, `socket1.py` needs to bind to the port. zeromq will turn that into a listen for the client to connect.

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.bind("tcp://localhost:{}".format(port))
print("Socket created")

i = 0
while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print("socket: msg recved")
    print(msg)
    socket.send_string("hello from 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```